# Adding a Hadoop Dispatcher listener for eventing

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am looking for a suggestion on how to listen for events from the Hadoop framework. I have spent quite a lot of time investigating solutions to this problem but have not come up with a reasonable solution. What I want is a way to add a bridge to listen for events from the MRAppMaster's dispatcher. I want to capture these events and forward the ones I care about to the listening client. This would allow me to detect when a job is complete without having to register a servlet callback as the JobCompletion functionality does. Has anyone found a way to register for events from the Dispatcher? I have modified the MrAppMaster to create an event bridge that I use to forward the events to an ActiveMQ server but this makes my version of hadoop specialized and non portable. Any ideas, I have heard that the TimeServer may help me add this functionality but am not sure how it works as of yet.